# How many Pokémon are in New Pokémon Snap?

Tags: new-pokemon-snap

How many pokemon are there in the game? How much pokemon should I have in my picturedex to have all those available in pokemon snap?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 214 pokemon in the new pokemon snap. Here they are:

> Abomasnow
>
> Absol
>
> Applin
>
> Archeops
>
> Aerodactyl
>
> Aipom
>
> Alomomola
>
> Altaria
>
> Arbok
>
> Ariados
>
> Audino
>
> Aurorus
>
> Avalugg
>
> Beartic
>
> Beautifly
>
> Beheeyem
>
> Bellossom
>
> Bewear
>
> Bidoof
>
> Blastoise
>
> Bouffalant
>
> Bounsweet
>
> Braviary
>
> Bulbasaur
>
> Bunnelby
>
> Cacnea
>
> Carbink
>
> Caterpie
>
> Celebi
>
> Chandelure
>
> Charizard
>
> Charmander
>
> Chinchou
>
> Clamperl
>
> Clefairy
>
> Clawitzer
>
> Combee
>
> Comfey
>
> Corsola
>
> Crabominable
>
> Crabrawler
>
> Cradily
>
> Crobat
>
> Croagunk
>
> Cubchoo
>
> Cutiefly
>
> Dedenne
>
> Deerling
>
> Delibird
>
> Dewgong
>
> Diancie
>
> Dodrio
>
> Drampa
>
> Drifblim
>
> Drifloon
>
> Ducklett
>
> Eevee
>
> Eldegoss
>
> Emolga
>
> Espeon
>
> Espurr
>
> Exeggutor
>
> Finneon
>
> Flareon
>
> Florges
>
> Flygon
>
> Frillish (Male and Female)
>
> Froslass
>
> Frosmoth
>
> Furret
>
> Gangar
>
> Gardevoir
>
> Geodude
>
> Glaceon
>
> Glalie
>
> Golisopod
>
> Golurk
>
> Goodra
>
> Graveler
>
> Grookey
>
> Heliolisk
>
> Heracross
>
> Hippowdon
>
> Hoothoot
>
> Ho-Oh
>
> Houndoom
>
> Hydreigon
>
> Inkay
>
> Jirachi
>
> Jolteon
>
> Joltik
>
> Jynx
>
> Kangaskhan
>
> Kecleon
>
> Lanturn
>
> Lapras
>
> Leafeon
>
> Ledian
>
> Liepard
>
> Lotad
>
> Lugia
>
> Lumineon
>
> Luvdisc
>
> Luxray
>
> Lycanroc
>
> Machamp
>
> Madibuzz
>
> Magikarp
>
> Mamoswine
>
> Mantine
>
> Mareanie
>
> Mawile
>
> Meganium
>
> Metapod
>
> Mew
>
> Mightyena
>
> Milotic
>
> Minior (Meteor and Core Form)
>
> Monferno
>
> Morelull
>
> Murkrow
>
> Natu
>
> Noibat
>
> Noivern
>
> Ninetales
>
> Octillery
>
> Onix
>
> Pancham
>
> Pelipper
>
> Phione
>
> Pichu
>
> Pidgeot
>
> Pikachu
>
> Pikipek
>
> Pinsir
>
> Primarina
>
> Piplup
>
> Pumpkaboo
>
> Purrloin
>
> Pyukumuku
>
> Quagsire
>
> Qwilfish
>
> Raichu (Alolan)
>
> Rampardos
>
> Rattata
>
> Sableye
>
> Salandit
>
> Sandshrew
>
> Sandslash (Alolan)
>
> Sandyghast
>
> Sawsbuck
>
> Serperior
>
> Seviper
>
> Scorbunny
>
> Sharpedo
>
> Shaymin
>
> Shiftry
>
> Shinx
>
> Silicobra
>
> Skarmory
>
> Skorupi
>
> Slaking
>
> Slugma
>
> Snom
>
> Snorunt
>
> Sobble
>
> Spheal
>
> Squirtle
>
> Starly
>
> Starmie
>
> Steelix
>
> Stoutland
>
> Stunfisk
>
> Sudowoodo
>
> Suicune
>
> Swampert
>
> Swanna
>
> Swinub
>
> Syglyph
>
> Sylveon
>
> Taillow
>
> Talonflame
>
> Tangrowth
>
> Tentacuel
>
> Torchic
>
> Torkoal
>
> Torterra
>
> Toucannon
>
> Trapinch
>
> Trevenant
>
> Trubbish
>
> Typhlosion
>
> Tyranitar
>
> Tyrantrum
>
> Umbreon
>
> Unfezant
>
> Vanilluxe
>
> Vaporeon
>
> Venesaur
>
> Vespiquen
>
> Vivillon
>
> Volcarona
>
> Vulpix (Alolan)
>
> Wailmer
>
> Wailord
>
> Weavile
>
> Wingull
>
> Wishiwashi (Solo and School Form)
>
> Woobat
>
> Wooper
>
> Wurmple
>
> Xerneas
>
> Yanmega
>
> Zangoose

[Source](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/List_of_Pok%C3%A9mon_by_Photodex_order)