# Where do you find Mew?

Tags: new-pokemon-snap

I noticed from [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/385513/how-many-pok%c3%a9mon-are-in-new-pok%c3%a9mon-snap) that Mew is in the game.  However I've beaten the game and never even saw one.  **Where is Mew?**

Please provide a hint rather than a solution.  Or at least, put the solution in a spoiler tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mew, along with the other legendaries, **[cannot be seen until you've completed the game](https://www.ign.com/wikis/new-pokemon-snap/Legendary_Pokemon#All_Legendary_Pokemon_Locations_in_New_Pokemon_Snap)** so even if you've explored every inch of every course, you will have to replay them after the story is done if you want to complete the photodex.

Mew can be found in

> [Founja Jungle at night](https://www.ign.com/wikis/new-pokemon-snap/Mew#How_to_Capture_the_Four_Star_Mew_Photo).

There's only so many things you can do, so that should be enough info to get you started, but if you still can't find him after a few tries:

> when you enter the course, immediately turn around and play the melody

and if you want the four-star photo

> hit Mew's bubble with a fluffruit three times, then play the melody at the ruins after the cliff.  Mew should appear and allow you to snap a photo

Comment: "There's only so many things you can do, so that should be enough info to get you started" -> I dunno, triggering Lugia was pretty tricky :)

Comment: I actually found it accidentally while trying to max out my research on that level.  When in doubt, constantly play music, look everywhere, take a picture of everything and throw lumina orbs and fluffruit at every Pokémon.